# Receiving payments from iTunes - are there foreign currency exchange fees?

Tags: itunes, applications, app-store-connect, exchange

Apple collects payments for our apps in many currencies, converts all of them to our country's currency (CAD), then sends it to us in a single payment.

My question: Does Apple charge a foreign currency exchange fee for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You will be paid by units sold. Let's see an example:

You sold 100 apps with a price of 1 CAD.

You will get 0.7 CAD per app sold x 100 units.

Total 70.0 CAD.

If some of your sales are on foreign country, the process is the same, except currency exchange applied is the payment's day exchange, without fees.

This quoted text is from [iTunes Connect Payments and Financial Reports](https://itunesconnect.apple.com):

> This amount is only an estimate. Actual amount may vary, based on
>   foreign exchange rates. Amount shown does not include any applicable
>   withholding tax, which will be applied when the payment is made.

Comment: You're sure they don't charge a fee or increase the spread?  Almost every other institution (banks, Paypal, credit cards) charge a currency conversion fee, usually hidden in the actual conversion.

That would be fantastic if they did not charge a fee, but seems unlikely.

Comment: Sure. And your can review yourself on iTunes Connect. Once you received the first payment, you can download earning reports by country and see it for yourself.